# Python giving "module' object has no attribute 'message_from_string' error

Tags: python, email

I am moving from C# to Python, and I am guessing I am stepping on some namesapce issue, but I can't find the problem.  Here is the current class that is giving me error (on line 41)

```
import imaplib
import os
import email

class EmailWrapper:

hostname = None     # herp
username = None     # derp
password = None     # might encrypt this if there is time

def __init__(self, host, user, passwd):
    self.hostname = host
    self.username = user 
    self.password = passwd

# Create connection and return it
def connect(self, verbose=True):
    if verbose: print 'Connecting to ', self.hostname
    connection = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL(self.hostname)
    if verbose: print 'Logging in as ', self.username
    connection.login(self.username, self.password)
    if verbose: print 'Selecting Inbox.'
    connection.select('Inbox')
    return connection

# Grab last email in inbox and return it from connection
def get_last_email(self, c):
    # Get list of emails
    result, data = c.search(None, "ALL")

    # get last ID
    ids = data[0]  
    idList = ids.split()
    lastEmailID = idList[-1]

    # Fetch email
    result, data = c.fetch(lastEmailID, "(RFC822)")

    # Seclect body and return it
    rawEmail = data[0][1]
    emailMessage = email.message_from_string(rawEmail)
    return emailMessage


def close_connection(self, c):
    c.close()
    c.logout()
```

Any time I call get_last_email I get the error "AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'message_from_string'".  Any ideas would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Does the example [here](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/email.parser.html#email.message_from_binary_file) work when you put it in a interactive prompt?

Comment: Yes, no error there.

Comment: What's the output of `dir(email)`? You don't happen to have a file called `email.py` in the same folder, right?

Comment: Son of a **** mother ****** I did!  It was the first script I was messing with.  Jesus, thanks.  I R the dumb.  Thank you @jDo - that was the problem.

Comment: @OmegaNine I knew it! :D You're welcome! Glad it's solved

Answer (score 7):

The problem, as pointed out by @jDo, was that i still had an empty email.py file sitting around in the project directory.  Thanks!